# Search through PDF with word distance?

Tags: windows, pdf, search, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

Is it possible to search in a PDF ( via acrobat reader / foxit) - text with word distance ?

For example :

I'm looking for the word `"static"` and I know that another word  which is  `"field"` - should be around. I also assume that the distance between them is `<=` 50 words.

**Question**

Is there anyway I can search pdf with that kind of search ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible in Adobe Reader XI (and possibly earlier versions).

1. Open **Adobe Reader**
2. Open **Advanced Search Options** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Open **Even more Advanced Search Options** by clicking `Show More Options` at the bottom of the search Window.
4. Set the search to the folder you have the document in.
5. Set the return results to `Match all of the words`
6. Type the Word or phrase you want to search for.
7. Check the Proximity search checkbox.
8. Press Search.

[image]

The default range for proximity search is 900 words. If that is too much for you, go to File → Preferences → Search and reduce it.

[image]

[Further reading on Advanced Search options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/standard/using/WS047F7D61-E05E-4e82-98BA-F84B2E7A5974.w.html)

Comment: What can I say -   you're the man. wait 17 hr for selected bounty